# Laravel mysql if else condition

Tags: mysql

How to use if else condition in mysql

Here is my code

```
$couponQry = Coupon::select('*')
    ->where('generate_coupon', '=', 0)
    ->where('coupon_soft_delete', '=', 0)
    ->where('expiry_date', '>=', date('Y-m-d'))
    ->whereRaw("(coupon_limitation=1 AND coupon_usage>coupon_used) OR (coupon_limitation=0 AND coupon_used>=0)");

$couponData = $couponQry->get();

coupon_limitation | coupon_usage | coupon_used | generate_coupon
1                    1                 1           0
0                    0                 5           0
```

Here I have to get second row only. Because coupon_limitation is 1 and if coupon_limitation is 1 coupon_usage should be greater than coupon_used (Active coupons, Unlimited coupon use). If coupon_usage and coupon_used are equal and coupon_limitation 1 coupon validity end (Archived coupon, limited coupon use).

If coupon_limitation is 0 I don't need to check coupon_used and coupon_usage (Always active until expiry date end).
Thanks

Comment: What is not working currently?

Comment: I am getting false result. I set coupon limit is 1 and used 1 coupon, but I am getting result. Because of OR condition.

Comment: So you mean `coupon_usage` was `0`?

Comment: Edit your question to include sample data in your table, and expected output.

Comment: Are you saying that the query is returning both rows shown when you only want the second one?

Answer (score 0):

I did like this and working fine

```
$couponQry = Coupon::select('*')
    ->where('generate_coupon', '=', 0)
    ->where('coupon_soft_delete', '=', 0)
    ->where('expiry_date', '>=', date('Y-m-d'))
    ->whereRaw("CASE WHEN coupon_limitation=1 THEN coupon_usage>coupon_used ELSE coupon_usage>=0 END");

$couponData = $couponQry->get();
```